# HTTP/2 Server Push NGINX 1.13.9

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Прочитал, что в версии nginx 1.13.9 появилась интересная штука, вроде server push. 
В инструкции есть пример, где в конфигурации:

```
location = /demo.html {
    http2_push /style.css;
    http2_push /image1.jpg;
    http2_push /image2.jpg;
}
```

То есть вроде все понятно, при открытии такой-то страницы, сервер пушит такие-то файлы. Но что не понятно, так это как этим добром пользоваться в реальной жизни.

То есть, у меня куча страниц, большинство использует одни и те же стили. Мне же не писать это правило в конфиге для каждой страницы. Если я прикручу к главной странице пуш этих файлов, а человек откроет мой сайт с другой?

Подскажите правильное применение, пожалуйста

Comment: `location / { root ...; http2_push /style.css; }`

Comment: @norbornen то есть у меня есть   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }, и я просто в него впихиваю файлы, что нужны для каждой страницы?

Comment: в общих чертах - да, - в `location / {}` и в location который проксирует запросы на бекенд